# Triggering Pikaday date picker script on input field and icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, pikaday

I'm trying to use the [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) date picker script and it's working fine, however I want to trigger it on clicking in the field as well as on an icon.

I am using the `jQuery` method to bind it, such as:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: $('#used_from')[0]
});
```

Which works fine, but then I tried out the *trigger* option as mentioned in the docs, as such..

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: $('#used_from')[0],
    trigger: $('#used_from_cal')[0],
});
```

This works too, but *only* on the element with the `used_from_cal` id; it no longer works on the input field with the id `used_from`.

I tried using multiple selectors, such as:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: $('#used_from, #used_from_calc')[0]
});
```

...but this only worked on the first element.

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWJyQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible out of the box, seeing this in the Pikaday source:

```
opts.trigger = (opts.trigger && opts.trigger.nodeName) ? opts.trigger : opts.field;
```

There's just one trigger, being the `trigger` or the `field`.

You can hack your way around it a bit by doing something like:

```
  document.getElementById("used_from_cal").addEventListener("click", function(){
    picker.show();
  });
```

Check it out here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaXBmQ

Answer (score 1):

i know that's not a right way but maybe will help you.

```
 $(document).ready(function($) {
          var picker = new Pikaday({
            field: $('#used_from')[0]
          });

          $('#used_from_cal').click(function() {
           $('.pika-single.is-bound').removeClass('is-hidden'); 
           $('.pika-single.is-bound').css('position', 'absolute');
           $('.pika-single.is-bound').css('position', '36px');
           $('.pika-single.is-bound').css('left', '10px');
          });
      });
```